# OpenFileDialog crashes under Windows XP, but not Windows 7

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, crash, openfiledialog

I've got a strange problem I haven't seen before.  I can open an `OpenFileDialog` in Windows 7 without any problems.  However, when I try my app on Windows XP, calling `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` immediately crashes the application.  It just vanishes!  When running from the debugger, I don't get any unhandled exceptions.  If I wrap the code in a try/catch block, nothing gets caught.  I have also checked all thrown exceptions in Debug -> Exceptions, but nothing pops up.  I'll try some of the other suggestions in the answers below and will report back.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?  I found a [post about something similar](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/589316/microsoft-win32-openfiledialog-microsoft-win32-savefiledialog-crash-in-aero-windows-7-theme), but it was the opposite problem.  I'll try tweaking the desktop settings to see if it's related to that, but I am dubious.

EDIT -- as a sanity check, I wrote a test WPF application that displays an `OpenFileDialog` directly via the main window as well as another `Window` that can be displayed by the main window.  It totally works fine under Windows XP.  So now I'm really confused.  I have verified that I'm not doing something stupid like trying to display the dialog from a worker thread.  The `OpenFileDialog` displays briefly, then disappears along with the application.

EDIT -- I'm going to try to reproduce this problem on another XP computer.  For now, I'll try Windows XP mode and we'll see what happens.

Comment: Marking my own question as possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550030/c-wpf-openfiledialog-causing-crash-in-xp-not-in-vista

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate after all.  I checked the XP computer and it has pretty much all of the .NET Framework versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

I  got a similar error when a DLL crashes when I open a OpenFileDialog. It turned out that OpenFileDialog changed the working directory so my dll tried to write to a relative file that did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any "First Chance" exceptions in the Output? Any entries in the event log? Does the default path you're using exist on the XP machine?

Try adding a handler to the App Domain's `UnhandledException`

Does the same happen when you use a brand new, stock `FileOpenDialog` without any tweaks? What about from a brand new app which does nothing but show a file open dialog?

Comment: Ah, I'll look at the default path -- great suggestion!

Comment: Verified it exists -- still crashes.

Comment: How about a brand new winforms app? Does the dialog work from there? Then we can identify app problem/environment problem

Comment: I just added more detail do my original question.  I have created a new WPF app and it works fine.  So now the question is, why does my real app work on Win7 and not XP?  Very, very baffling problem...

Comment: Next step in narrowing it down, try and open a dialog in your app sing all the default settings (no customisation). Assuming that fails, consider turning .Net framework debugging - You'll also need to enable downloading of symbol for the .Net framework - all in settings-debugging IIRC. This will allow you to step into the framework code and try to debug the issue. BTW Are you using reflection or an IoC container to create concretes?

Comment: @Basiclife thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow.  I'm using MEF for some object creation, and the component that crashes is indeed instantiated via MEF.

Comment: When concretes are instantiated by reflection (or oC containers), you don't get fully-featured bebugging - Which may hint at a reason why it's dropping out on you without warning

Comment: @Basiclife I haven't heard of that before -- I also haven't had any issues until now debugging any sort of problems that crop up.  Do you have any information online regarding this?

Comment: IF you're debugging an x86 app, ome of the advanced features (Edit-And-Continue, etc.) don't work. [See Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/b2a38f4c-349d-4bbc-a65d-c4d5d670c334)

Answer (score 0):

See [Galet's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738327/c-app-runs-with-debugging-but-not-without)

---

I cannot tell you what exactly the problem is, but here's what you could do to get a clue what's really happening. I assume you're using VS2008 or 2005.

1.Switch to release mode
2.Go to Debug\Exceptions, and mark all "Thrown" exceptions, like illustrated here: http://vvcap.net/db/JbWS_tzy2IpBoI7R7amm.htp
3.Run executable in debugger, ignore the warnings from VS that there's no debug info
It does seem that there's a win32 exception thrown some time during execution, but this way or another, you will get one or more messages from debugger explaining what kind of exception happened and where. In most cases those messages make it pretty clear what exactly went wrong

EDIT: One thing I forgot to mention is that unmanaged debugging must also be turned on, such like here (when you start program directly from IDE) or here (when you attach to running process)
link|edit|flag edited Apr 12 '09 at 22:32

answered Apr 10 '09 at 19:01
galets
1,2201924

Comment: I should have mentioned it in my post, but I did mark all thrown exceptions -- nothing pops up.  I'm in VS2010, and I edited my tags to reflect that.

Comment: I enabled unmanaged debugging, and also checked everything in the Thrown columns.  It's still disappearing w/o any information.